# Conditional Expectation of Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $Y$ be a random variable of density g. How could I compute the expectation

$E[Y|Y<a]$ ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

If $P(Y<a)>0$ and $EY$ exists.
$$E[Y|Y<a] = \frac{E[Y\cdot1_{\{Y<a\}}]}{P(Y<a)} = \frac{\int\limits_{-\infty}^a xg(x)dx}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^a g(x)dx}$$

Comment: Didn't quite understand what $E[Y\cdot1_{Y<a}]$ means

Comment: @Vizag is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's been over 2 years, but I suggest this answer
$$
E(Y|Y<a) = \frac{E(Y \times (Y < a))}{P(Y<a)}
= \frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (t \times c(t)) f_{Y}(t) dt  }{ \int_{-\infty}^{a}{ f_{Y}(y) dy } }
$$
where
$$
c(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1, & t < a \\
0, & {\rm otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Hence, we have
$$
E(Y|Y<a) = \frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{a} t f_{Y}(t) dt  }{ \int_{-\infty}^{a}{ f_{Y}(y) dy } }.
$$